# HP Pavilion 15 Notebook won't install UBUNTU

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hp, raid

I have been trying to install the latest Ubuntu on my hp pavilion 15 notebook and it will not let it install.  I keep getting the error message about turning off RST and I have tried literally everything I can think of or have found till the point I've broke the Raid setup in the SSD drive and Windows 10 will not boot up well which is fine. I honestly don't care if I have windows on this machine or not, was hoping to dual boot but if I need to just totally wipe it clean and install Ubuntu Id be just fine with that. Any guidance or help/ suggestions would be appreciated greatly. Thank you.  If you need any details or info to help me figure this out just let me know.

Comment: Please be specific with details; you mention the *latest* Ubuntu which is Ubuntu 23.10, but not which Ubuntu 23.10 product, ie. Ubuntu Server using the `subiquity` installer, or Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop which offers two installers, `ubiquity` on the *legacy* ISO and `ubuntu-desktop-installer` on the defualt ISO, so which did you attempt to install?  Did you verify ISO as being valid?  Did the media verification complete?  (*if it doesn't complete on the machine you're installing to, I'd suggest using another box to verify media, as no installation is required to verify media*)